# how to exclude the row which has lookup value in vlookup in excel automation using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vlookup

is there any way to use vlookup or index and match functions in Excel exclude the entire row which has lookup value in the table array in VB.NET?

For example: 
I have a table array like

101  2    200    500

102  5    200    450

103  3   200    750

101   2   200   450

103   5   200    500

> lookup value :103 (A3)
>
> table array:A1:D5
>
> column:4 (500)

For example I am looking for 103 (ie A3 cell value) in the table array. I want D5 cell value. But I am getting the D3 cells value (ie the row itself): 750 instead of 500 in the 5th row. So I want to exclude the look up value of that row while searching.
Is it possible? Please guide me.

i have a lot of rows with data in Excel sheet. so i am  directly using vlookup with for loop.
This is my code:

For ii As Integer = 0 To i20 - 1

```
        bmatint(ii, 0) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "B" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,1,FALSE)"
        bmatint(ii, 1) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "B" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,16,FALSE)"
        bmatint(ii, 2) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "B" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,17,FALSE)"
        bmatint(ii, 3) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "I" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,1,FALSE)"
        bmatint(ii, 4) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "I" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,16,FALSE)"
        bmatint(ii, 5) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "I" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,17,FALSE)"
```

Next

it gives wrong results as i explained above.

gvg

Comment: i suspect that your vlookup syntex is wrong. it goes like this:

VLOOKUP(" & Chr$(34) & excelSheetName " & Chr$(34) & ",RANGE,COLUMN,FALSE/TRUE)

use your actual variable

Comment: it's working fine. but it also considering lookup value row also. that is giving worng results.

Comment: that is because you are using COLUMN#1 in first line of your FOR loop above.


bmatint(ii, 0) = "=VLOOKUP( " & "B" & ii + 2 & " ,B2:R15000,1,FALSE)"

Comment: how to do it correctly. exclude the row which has lookup_value.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with an if statement, see the pseudocode below:

```
if A1.Value = myValue and currentRow <> 3 then
     '''your return code
     return Column(4).CurrentRow.Value  
endif
```

please post your code for a detailed answer